# Error E0412: use of undeclared crate or module `tokio` when importing tokio::sync

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

In my rust project, cargo complains about a used type not being in scope when using tokio::sync:

```
use tokio::sync::RwLock;
  |     ^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `tokio`
```

but it clearly is in scope:

```
use tokio::sync::RwLock;

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    some_field: RwLock<SomeType>
}
```

According to the documentation, the sync module is only available after enabling the `sync` feature flag, which I have done both explicitly and implicitly:

```
tokio = { version = "0.3", features = ["macros", "sync"] }
tokio = { version = "0.3", features = ["full"] }
```

But it does not work with either.

Comment: Have you added the `extern crate tokio;` declaration in your `main.rs` or `lib.rs`?

Comment: Yep, but I :face-palm: figured out why I was getting this error. I only had tokio under the dev-dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't notice that I only had tokio under the dev-dependencies, which is why cargo was not able to compile the project.